# What happens if an exception occurs in Kernel mode?

Tags: exception, kernel, cpu

I heard a couple of times that in Kernel mode, nothing is protecting you.

For example if you divide by zero, nothing will catch you, as the exception handling mechanism works only for user mode.

But that doesn't make sense.
The IVT is still there, it doesn't matter if this is Kernel mode or user mode.
Why won't the CPU simply jump to the regular exception handling routine and solve the issue?
It can't send a signal, but it can handle it otherwise...

So my question is what does that mean, that nothing is protecting you?

Comment: `Why won't the CPU simply jump to the regular exception handling routine and solve the issue?` - What do you mean by "solve"? For user-space errors, "solving" normally implies **killing** the erroneous process. Because  user-space processes are *isolated* (by memory) one from another, killing the one doesn't harm others. `nothing is protecting you` means that in kernel there is **no isolation** between processes: error in one process may harm any other one.. or entire system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev But division by zero in a printer driver (that is run in Kernel mode, if I understand correctly) shouldn't crash the whole system. Should it?

Comment: It can. E.g., if division occures with spinlock taken. Another side: division by zero means that driver's algorithm isn't work properly, so harm to the other system's components could be already done at the time of the division.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, just to be clear: When Kernel mode code causes an exception the regular exception handling routine (the same one for user mode) is executed, indentifies that the exception happened in Kernel mode and triggers a Kernel panic?

Comment: This is true except from "Kernel panic". Normally, kernel just "stops" the thread which cause the exception. It *assumes* that other threads may work correctly. But an assumption may be false, which can cause almost any effect. E.g., freezing the system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So in both Kernel mode and user mode the handler will terminate the offending block of code, but the difference is that in user mode no other processes will have major problems because of that (because of isolation), but in Kernel mode there isn't such gurantee. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly this `nothing is protecting you` means when talk about the kernel..

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: What OS are we even talking about here?